# Insert operation in two different classes with one post request

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

I want to insert mysql and redis databases in their classes at the same time. I tried to use the repository pattern, but laravel's bind method implements the interface to only one single class

The controller is as follows:

```php
class PostController extends Controller
{
    protected $post;

    public function __construct(PostRepositoryInterface $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function store(StorePostRequest $request, PostRepositoryInterface $post)
    {
        return $post->create($request->validated());
    }
}
```

PostRepositoryInterface

```php
interface PostRepositoryInterface
{
    public function all();

    public function get($id);

    public function create($param);

    public function update($id, $param);

    public function delete($id);
}
```

The question I want to ask is, how can I perform the insert operation in more than one class using this interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way code-wise would be to use model observers on your resource and listen for CRUD events.

The observer class would interact with a second repository to replicate the changes in the second data source.

Here you can take a look at the official [model events documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events)

Comment: Yes i know model events. But i want to use patterns and solid principles. I was wondering how a professional data management would be.